# Creating a serial actually creates a bigserial

Tags: postgresql, int, bigint

When I create a test table with a serial type,
The serial is actually a bigserial type.
Does this cause any issues?
Is this a bug?
PostgreSQL 9.5.3
Red Hat 64-bit

```
#> CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name text);
#> \d+ test
    Table "public.test"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name   | text    |                                                   | extended |              | 
Indexes:
"test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

#> \d+ test_id_seq
    Sequence "public.test_id_seq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        | Storage 
---------------+---------+---------------------+---------
 sequence_name | name    | test_id_seq         | plain
 last_value    | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 start_value   | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807 | plain
 min_value     | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1                   | plain
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0                   | plain
 is_cycled     | boolean | f                   | plain
 is_called     | boolean | f                   | plain
```

Answer (score 1):

`SERIAL` isn't really a type; as explained in the [9.5 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), it's just shorthand for a collection of commands:

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types, but merely a notational convenience [...] In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

As you can see, the `integer` type applies only to the table column, and is not mentioned in the definition of the sequence. The [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html) statement in 9.5 doesn't allow you to specify a type; all sequences are based on `bigint` counters, hence the `bigint` columns in your `\d+` output.

This is no longer the case, as of Postgres 10: you can now attach a data type to a sequence, and as per the [new docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), the sequence in the `SERIAL` example above is now defined as:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
```

This really only serves to limit the max value of the sequence - the internal counter is still a `bigint` - but it is reported as the appropriate type by `\d+` (which now looks quite different):

```
test=# \d+ tablename_colname_seq
               Sequence "public.tablename_colname_seq"
  Type   | Start | Minimum |  Maximum   | Increment | Cycles? | Cache
---------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-------
 integer |     1 |       1 | 2147483647 |         1 | no      |     1
```